# How do I escape these ampersands in PHP?

Tags: php, json, escaping, steam, steam-web-api

I'm currently writing something that uses the Steam web API and I'm trying to get the Steam market price via the web API like so:

```
$url = 'http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name='.$itemInfo['market_hash_name'];
```

The `$itemInfo['market_hash_name']` is something from another JSON I got from the API.

That should return something like this:

```
http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=SCAR-20 | Contractor (Well-Worn)
```

and it does, which is fine, because when I throw that into the browser, it translate into

```
http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=SCAR-20%20|%20Contractor%20(Well-Worn)
```

which returns the JSON I need.

But for some reason when it's used with `get_file_contents`, it translates the ampersands like so:

```
http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=3&amp;appid=730&amp;market_hash_name=Operation Breakout Weapon Case
```

Which returns nothing if I throw it into a browser window. So it doesn't really matter if I use `htmlspecialchars` or `html_entity_decode`, because whenever I put it into `get_file_contents` it just encodes the ampersands once again.

How am I to do this?

Comment: When you see `http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=SCAR-20%20|%20Contractor%20(Well-Worn)` are you viewing the source or output in the browser?

Comment: When I run this, it returns success:

`var_dump(file_get_contents('http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=SCAR-20 | Contractor (Well-Worn)'));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So it doesnt really matter if i use htmlspecialchars or html_entity_decode, cuz whenever i put it into get_file_contents it just encodes the ampersands once again.

Neither of those is for ***URI***-encoding. That's the job of [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php).

So:

```
$url = 'http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name='.urlencode($itemInfo['market_hash_name']);
```

Comment: I already tried urlencode, but ofc it only has to be on the itemInfo... My bad, and thank you :)